# Required Package in combination meteor+react+react-bootstrap

Tags: meteor, reactjs, react-bootstrap, meteor-react

I used the following packages individually and combined

```
$ meteor add react
$ meteor add firfi:meteor-react-bootstrap
```

When I used the `react` package, bootstrap is not working.

If I use `firfi:meteor-react-bootstrap`, the react package is not working.

When I used both packages there is an error

> ***Uncaught Error***: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's `render` method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.

Can anyone suggest a package for **react** and **react-bootstrap** for **meteor**?

**My Code**:

```
var { Modal,Button,Input} = ReactBootstrap;
if (Meteor.isClient){    
   Meteor.startup(function () {        
   console.log("METEOR STARTUP");
   React.render(<MyModal/>, document.getElementById('modal-container'));
});
}


var MyModal = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="modal-open">
            <Modal
                title='Modeltest'
                backdrop={true}
                animation={false}
                closeButton={true}
                onRequestHide={() => {}}>    
                <div className='modal-body'>
                    <p>Check the Modal body</p>
                </div>
            </Modal>
        </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few alternatives, and the set that works best for me today is:

```
react                     0.1.13  Everything you need to use React with Meteor.
twbs:bootstrap            3.3.5  The most popular front-end framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
universe:react-bootstrap  0.24.0  ReactBootstrap project wrapped for Meteor with Universe:modules
```

Version 0.24 is a bit old today, but you cannot use the latest React-Bootstrap anyway, since it requires React 0.14 which Meteor has not yet upgraded to. (See Meteor [issue #116](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/issues/116))