# Meteor / React / React-Bootstrap Building Failure

Tags: reactjs, meteor, npm, react-bootstrap

I want to use Meteor with React and react-bootstrap. I've found many 'marks' of how to install but I think they are all outdated.

```
// packages/client-deps/package.js
  Package.describe({
  name: 'client-deps'
});

Npm.depends({
  'react-bootstrap': '0.28.1', 
  'react' : '0.14.3' 
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.use(['cosmos:browserify@0.3.0']); 

  api.addFiles(['app.browserify.js']); 
  api.export(['ReactBootstrap', 'React']); 
});
```

and

```
React = require('react/addons');
ReactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');
```

After this, I installed `meteor add reactrouter:react-router` ...
But nothing is displayed ( works without client-deps stuff ) / no error message.

- [Required Package in combination meteor+react+react-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047361/required-package-in-combination-meteorreactreact-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer is very old, but it would be worth answering for 2017.
I just made a Meteor project to test this, and I followed the documentation here: https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap and Bootstrap was added.

You can just run `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` and it adds Bootstrap and Meteor takes care of all the dependencies for you.